# How to intercept context menu item selection in IE? SPY++ doesn't receive WM_COMMAND on any IE window

Tags: internet-explorer, ieaddon

Once a user clicks right clicks on some webpage in IE, a context popup menu is shown to user which contains some items like Print, View source and some other custom items.

Now i know how to add some entries in this context menu, but my requirement is to intercept a menu selection (like right click -> Print) on this popup menu...

So i started capturing messages on IE windows using SPY++ and i am able to uniquely determine the context menu item highlight with WM_MENUSELECT message. (id:27 for highlighting Print item). However once i select the print item (mouse click or keyboard Enter), there is no WM_COMMAND received on ANY of the IE windows... no WM_MENUCOMMAND either...

So i was just wondering How could IE have implemented its menu selection handling without using standard WM_COMMAND messages?? Is there an alternative to this or I am missing something??

So as of now only alternative left with me is to save state on MENUSELECT event and then check this state in next LBUTOONCLICK/ Keyboard enter events... is there any other clean way? please suggest...